# Put results from .load() php file into Var

Tags: php, jquery, get

I have a page that loads in "get-results.php" which loads the results into a div. This works great. However, I also need to grab a variable from the php file that is being loaded, so that I can re-include it in the .load() url, this way I can have the php file have the previous result for comparison.

```
$(".results").load("get-results.php" + "?userClicked=" + var1 + var2 + "&prevresult=" + theResults);
```

In the "get-results.php" file, I have set

```
var theResults = "<?php echo $result; ?>";
```

Is there a way for me to access "var theResults" from the page that is loading it (outer page, not inner)? How can I get the Var from the file and put it into a Var in the outer file? Any pointers would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var theresults;
    $(".results").load("get-results.php" + "?userClicked=" + var1 + var2 + "&prevresult=" + theResults,function() {
        theresults=$(".results").html();
       }));
```

obviously you have to wait the load is complete to get the new value for theresults.
otherwise, you can use `$.get` which seems more appropriate here :

```
      $.get("get-results.php" + "?userClicked=" + var1 + var2 + "&prevresult=" + theResults,function(data) {
         theresults=data;
         $(".results").html(data);
   }))
```

edit : if you are indeed sending more than this php var, you should send back a json (with your variables to be sent in an array then you `echo json_encode($arrayofvar)` then in the js you'll retrieve a json object of your var in the getJSOn callback

Comment: I actually only need one variable since the result is just a number, so the first option did just what I needed. I had no clue you could grab content from within a HTML element like that. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

No you can not, i.e if you are sending other things with the variable.

If you are sending only that variable ( which I think you are not), then use the above answer.

Else

try this one:

in php file:

```
var theResults = "<?php echo $result; ?>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$theResults ."' id='theResults'/>";
```

in javascript file:

```
$(".results").load("get-results.php" + "?userClicked=" + var1 + var2 + "&prevresult=" + theResults,function() {
        theresults=$("#theResults").val(); alert(theresults);
       }));
```